# VSCode Prettier extension not working when using prettier.config.cjs with prettier-plugin-tailwindcss and pnpm

Tags: tailwind-css, prettier, pnpm

I want to sort tailwindcss classes so

- Used [prettier-plugin-tailwindcss](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss#installation) and added `prettier.config.cjs` to root of the project as using **pnpm** package manager
- VSCode Prettier extension `v9.15.0`
- package.json prettier `"prettier": "2.8.8",`
- package.json having `"type": "module",`
- This is Typescript project

Getting following 2 errors:

**Error 1:** Error in editor

[prettier.config.cjs error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXs70.png)

**Error 2:** While saving any file

```
["ERROR" - 20:13:52] Error formatting document.
["ERROR" - 20:13:52] parse(a,m,f={}){let{context:s,generateRules:l}=dI(f),c=Wm(ws,e,f);c.astFormat in vv&&(f.printer=vv[c.astFormat]...<omitted>...d} could not be cloned.
DataCloneError: parse(a,m,f={}){let{context:s,generateRules:l}=dI(f),c=Wm(ws,e,f);c.astFormat in vv&&(f.printer=vv[c.astFormat]...<omitted>...d} could not be cloned.
    at new DOMException (node:internal/per_context/domexception:72:5)
    at Worker.postMessage (node:internal/worker:343:5)
    at t.PrettierWorkerInstance.callMethod (/home/rajbharti/.vscode-oss/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.15.0/dist/extension.js:1:17460)
    at t.PrettierWorkerInstance.format (/home/rajbharti/.vscode-oss/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.15.0/dist/extension.js:1:17078)
    at t.default.format (/home/rajbharti/.vscode-oss/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.15.0/dist/extension.js:1:14808)
    at async t.PrettierEditProvider.provideEdits (/home/rajbharti/.vscode-oss/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.15.0/dist/extension.js:1:11430)
    at async N.provideDocumentFormattingEdits (/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:101:52602)
["INFO" - 20:13:52] Formatting completed in 11ms.
```

**I tried following:**

- Renamed file extension from `prettier.config.js` to `prettier.config.cjs` as was getting ES module error.
- Added `/* eslint-disable no-undef */` to disable editor error in `prettier.config.cjs`, but still getting formatting error for files when saving

Comment: Started running into this myself in the last 24 hours.  VS Code 1.79.2?

Comment: Yes it is the same version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it also works with `v9.16.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Reverting to Prettier 9.14.0 (from 9.15.0) fixes this for me.

1. Right click on the extension in VS Code, click on "Install other version...".
2. Choose 9.14.0 from the list (reload required)
3. Go to your settings in VSCode, search for "Extensions: Auto Update".
4. Change this setting to "none" to avoid the extension updating automatically in the future.